# how could i change these code to MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

how could i change these code to MVC3 Razor,it script code.
these code i get form http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-5-master-page-templates.html
it's MVC2 Template and i want change it to Razor.

```
  <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
    <script runat="server">
        private object ModelValue {
            get {
                if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue == ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model) {
                    return String.Format(
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                        "{0:0.00}", ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model
                    );
                }
                return ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <%= Html.TextBox("", ModelValue, new { @class = "text-box single-line" }) %>
```

i changed to Razor as bellow but it can't work:

```
@{ 
    private object FormattedValue 
    {        
        get 
        {            
            if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue == ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model) 
            {                
                return String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,"{0:0.00}",ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model);
            }            
            return ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue;        
        }    
    }
}

@Html.Encode(FormattedValue)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own function:
http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2011/02/05/functions-inside-page-using-razor-view-engine-asp-net-mvc.aspx

just call the function passing it the value in, and return it however you want to format it.

```
@functions{
    public MvcString FormatValue(object valuetoFormat)
    {
        ...logic here ...
        return ....
    }
}
```

Calling it is roughly:

```
@Html.TextBox("", FormatValue(ModelValue), new { @class = "text-box single-line" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can specify adhoc properties in Razor. You can, however, create variables.

```
@{ 
    object FormattedValue;        
    if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue == ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model) 
    {                
        FormattedValue = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,"{0:0.00}",ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model);
    }else{
        FormattedValue = ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue;        
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you?

Comment: thanks, it's work and also i can use the function.thanks all of you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `@{  }` tag, the code is inserted inside the method used to generate the output.

You should use `@functions { }` to define elements you want on class (=page) level.

This would make your code look like:

[Read SLaks blog for more information.](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-6-function-blocks.html)

```
@functions { 
    private object FormattedValue 
    {        
        get 
        {            
            if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue == ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model) 
            {                
                return String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,"{0:0.00}",ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model);
            }            
            return ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue;        
        }    
    }
}

@Html.Encode(FormattedValue)
```